# which type of camera should be used for detecting road lanes for good processing in matlab

Tags: cameras

What are the parameters which should be selected to choose camera for lane detection system.What parameters should be kept in mind (like picture quality,frame rate,cost e.t.c). Which camera will suit best to my application.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on several things, mostly what your processing the images with, if you have a 1080p camera running at 60hz and your using a raspberry pie, that is clearly overkill. I would recommend you benchmark your platform of choice to come up with your ideal resolution to fps, and based on that select your resolution. The other factor will be focal length, witch  determines how wide an image your camra picks up (see the [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angle_of_view#Lens_types_and_effects)) having a lower focal length will allow you to pick up objects more to the left or right, but the only downside will be he bigger it is the less pixels your tracking target will pick up witch can become a problem as your resolution drops.